# C++: is there a way to limit who can instantiate a certain class, other than friendship?

Tags: c++

I would like to restrict which classes can create instances of some other ones.
I could use friendship, turning the constructor of the classes I want to restrict into a private one, but in some cases I can't modify the class code.

I'm wondering: is there another way to do it? Maybe some template magic using type Traits?

Comment: If you can't modify the classes, I can't see how this could be done.

Comment: ^^^ Pretty much. The right way to handle it is code review, or maybe a static analyzer written as a Clang tool.